# Downloading dependencies for a private gem in vendor/cache

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, dependency-management

We have created a gem for internal use only which is not hosted on any server. It is distributed to teams as a gem file, who then add it to their "vendor/cache" folder, and use Bundler to add it as a dependency.

The gemspec file in the gem project stipulates the require dependencies for our internal gem, but is not downloading them when "Bundle install" is used.  I assume this is because the list of dependencies is extracted from a call to the rubygems server rather than extracting from the Gem file itself??  If the dependencies are already in vendor/cache then all is fine.

Is there any way of instructing gem/bundler to get the list of dependencies from the gem itself rather than a server?

Is our only solution to create an internal Gem server?

Answer (score 0):

`bundle install` looks for dependencies in a `Gemfile` and ignores the `.gemspec`.

According to Rails Engine documentation:

"Declare your gem's dependencies in `clinkle_shared.gemspec`.  Bundler will treat runtime dependencies like base dependencies, and development dependencies will be added by default to the `:development` group.

Declare any dependencies that are still in development in a `Gemfile` instead of in your `.gemspec`. These might include edge Rails or gems from your path or Git. Remember to move these dependencies to your `.gemspec` before releasing your gem to rubygems.org."

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this.